# Responding with data to a Slack url in Express

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, heroku, slack-api

I have the following route in my Node backend with express middleware. My app uses the Slack backslash api to post a link to a user's channel. When user clicks it opens a form on an angular app hosted on heroku.

What I am looking to do is update the Slack user when the form get submitted.

So the question, how can I send a post request to slack url when the route below gets triggered(obviously the res is pointing to the /update). I've researched quite a bit and tried rewriting headers and using low level http methods, but I have a feeling there is a better solution to this. Many thanks for your help.

```
app.post("/update", function(req,res,next) {
    res url -> http://slackapi/12345/
    res.json({"text":"hello":}
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

res is not supposed to be sent to slack, this is the response to whoever contacted you. you need to send a different request to slack, and return whatever you want with res.

You can use [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) module to generate a http request to slack.

```
var request = require('request');

app.post("/update", function(req,res,next) {
  request('http://slackapi/12345/', function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      console.log(body);
      res.json({"text":"some answer to the requester"}); 
    } else {
      res.json({"text":"notify requester sending to slack falied"});
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks I don't mind using request, but is there an express way of doing it?

Comment: No, express is a module for server, it can recieve requests, not send them

Comment: Thanks. I ended up doing something like this
`var payload_slack ={"text":"Thanks "+, you rock!"};`
                        `var options = {
                            url:     slack_url,
                            method: "POST",
                            json:true,
                            body:payload_slack
                        };`

                        `request.post(options, function(error, response, body){
                            if(!err){
                                return res.json(resp);
                            }`
Where res is route redirect on angular side :)